# Понимание: Длина префикса

Tags: java, массивы

Всем привет, все никак не могу понять про префикс и суффикс каждого индекса в массиве!
Само понимание не приходит и как следствие реализация сравнения двух массивов по суффиксу и префиксу через цикл for( Кто по опытнее, подскажите как реализовать через цикл. Не используя готовые методы класса String.
Ниже код в котором пытался сравнить два массива, но не понимаю про длину префикса(

```
public class Char {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] word = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
        char[] pref = {'H', 'i'};
        System.out.println(starts(word, pref));
    }

    public static boolean starts(char[] lord, char[] proof) {
        boolean result = false;
        String string1 = new String(lord);
        String string2 = new String(proof);
        for (char c : lord) {
            if (c == proof[0]) {
                result = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: нифига не понятно =(

Comment: сравнить два массива по префиксу)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static boolean starts(char[] word, char[] pref) {
    for (int i = 0; i < pref.length; i++) {
        if (word[i] != pref[i]) {
          return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Я пробовал подобную конструкцию, но только word[i] == pref[i], оно не работало так ...  спасибо)